# Ambassador API gateway Features

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, api-gateway, ambassador

what are the features of the open-source Ambassador API gateway and what are the features of the enterprise version  Ambassador API gateway?

Answer (score 2):

The open source version of the Ambassador API Gateway is essentially the same product as the API Gateway included with the enterprise offering Edge Stack. The Edge Stack offered by Ambassador Labs is bundled with their additional products, (i.e. Service Preview and Developer Portal). It also offers additional functionality to the API gateway to extend it's capabilities, such as authentication integrations. Enterprise support is also included with the edge stack product. I suggest reading the ambassador labs docs or contacting them directly for the latest info.

https://www.getambassador.io/editions/